# Função com jQuery gravando em duas tabelas não persiste no BD

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-5

A minha necessidade é a seguinte: gravo em uma tabela, pego o ID gerado e gravo na segunda tabela com esse ID. Como a ordem é fazer isso em jQuery, foi feita uma função (por um colega). Mas infelizmente não consigo gravar.

Vejam que há duas chamadas no AJAX. Se eu removo a segunda etapa (persistir na segunda tabela), o código funciona. Mas quando habilito o segundo código, aí não funciona nada, nem a 1ª e nem a 2ª chamadas. Abaixo meu código jQuery. Se fosse pra fazer no Code Behind, eu saberia fazer, pois já fiz muito, mas com jQuery eu não estou conseguindo.

```
$(function () {
    $("#btnGravarPassageiros").click(function () {
        var result = {
            Id: 0,
            Nome: $("input[name ='txtNome']").val(),
            CPF: $("input[name='txtCep']").val(),
            Email: $("input[name='txtEmail']").val(),
            DataNascimento: $("input[name='txtAno']").val() + "-" + $("input[name='txtMes']").val() + "-" + $("input[name='txtDia']").val(),
            Telefone: $("input[name='txtTelefone']").val(),
            Celular: $("input[name='txtCelular']").val(),
            Endereco: $("input[name='txtLogradouro']").val(),
            Numero: $("input[name='txtNumero']").val(),
            CEP: $("input[name='txtCep']").val(),
            Complmento: $("input[name='txtComplemento']").val()
        };

        var result =  [];
        var resultado;
        var cont = 0;

        $.ajax({
            url: '/Passo/addCliente',
            dataType: "json",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            type: "POST",
            data: JSON.stringify({ _tb_clientes: result }),
            success: function (data) {
                alert(data.Result);
                $(".passageiro").each(function () {
                    nm = "txtNomePassageiro" + cont;
                    dia = "txtDiaPassageiro" + cont;
                    mes = "txtMesPassagecontro" + cont;
                    ano = "txtAnoPassagecontro" + cont;
                    sexo = "txtSexo" + cont;
                    numpassaporte = "txtPassaporte" + cont;
                    diavalidade = "txtDiaVal" + cont;
                    mesvalidade = "txtMesVal" + cont;
                    anovalidade = "txtAnoVal" + cont;
                    paisemissao = "txtPaisEmissao" + cont;
                    resultado = jQuery.parseJSON(
                        '{"Id_Cliente" : "' + data.Result +'" , "Nome": "' + $("input[name =" + nm + "]").val() +
                        '", "PassaPorte": "' + $("input[name =" + numpassaporte + "]").val() +
                        '", "DataNascimento": "' + $("input[name =" + dia + "-" + mes + "-" + ano + "]").val() + 
                        '", "Sexo": "' + $("input[name =" + sexo + "]").val() + '", "PassaPorteValidade": "' +
                        $("input[name =" + diavalidade + "-" + mesvalidade + "-" + anovalidade + "]").val() +
                        '", "PassaPortePais": "' + $("input[name =" + paisemissao + "]").val() + '" }');
                    result.push(resultado);

                    cont++;
                });

                $.ajax({
                    url: '/Passo/addClientePassageiro',
                    dataType: "json",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    type: "POST",
                    data: JSON.stringify({ _tb_clientes: result }),
                    success: function (data) {},
                    error: function (error) {}
                });                           
            },
            error: function (error) {}
        });
    });
});
```

Pessoal percebi o seguinte, que a função de gravar na minha controller, funciona, pelo menos na primeira fase(1ª tabela), mas no BD fica tudo `null`, como se estivesse reconhecendo os parâmetros passados do CSHTML. Isso está ocorrendo.

Answer (score 1):

Não parece haver erro algum nas chamadas Ajax, ao menos nada que chame a atenção e indique uma construção errada.

Note que o código que utiliza jQuery em seu exemplo apenas executa posts. É bastante provável que o erro aconteça do lado do servidor. Percebi que as funções de tratamento de erro estão vazias:

```
error: function (error) {}
```

Essas funções recebem três parâmetros ([vide documentação](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)). Sugiro que altere as funções de erro para a seguinte forma:

```
error: function (xhr, status, message) {
    // Aqui dentro você depura
}
```

Isso lhe permitirá ver qual é o verdadeiro erro que ocorre. Se for no lado do servidor, uma vez que você se diz experiente com .NET, acredito que lhe será algo fácil de resolver ;)

Answer (score -2):

O erro estava aqui:

```
var result =  [];
```

A variavel `result` já havia sido declarada. Alterei para:

```
var dados [];
```

Agora está gravando.